# Design automata for these languages

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, formal-languages, automata

I'm taking a Automata Theory and Formal Languages class, as homework I have to do this:

- a) Design a Finite Deterministic Automaton (FDA) that recognizes language $\{w\in \{a,b\}^* \, |\, w \mbox{ has as substrings  $ab$ and  $ba$.}\}$.
- b) Design a Finite Deterministic Automaton (FDA) that recognizes language $\{w\in \{a,b\}^* \, |\, w \text{ has as substrings $ab$ or $bba$.}\}$.

I have already done it, but I just would like to verify if the Automata are well designed.

- [Automaton for a)]
  (https://github.com/DavidHdezU/AutomataTheory/blob/main/Homeworks/H01/6a.png)

[image: Automaton for a]
[image]

- [Automaton for b](https://github.com/DavidHdezU/AutomataTheory/blob/main/Homeworks/H01/6B.png)

[image: Automaton for b]
[image]

Thank you!
PD: I don't know how to put the images here, sorry

Comment: Both look correct to me.  By the way, the singular of "automata" is "automaton."

Comment: Oh thanks! I'll fix that grammar error, thank you!

Comment: In your second automaton, $s_5$ and $s_1$ are equivalent.